# Passing a parameter from a parent to a child function

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to pass a parameter from a parent function to a child function while keeping the child function parameterless. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public static function parent($param)
{
    function child()
    {
        global $param;

        print($param) // prints nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: it is **VERY BAD** practice. do not do nested functions **EVER**

Comment: zerkms: would you explain why this is bad? I don't generally see any problems with it.

Comment: @fabric: sure, but it would be better if it had not ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: I know it is but the thing is I want the `child` function to exists only in the scope of the `parent` function so I figured that's the way to go.

Comment: @halfdan: `parent(1); parent(2);` -- what will that code produce?

Comment: @Emanuil: then you're wrong twice: symbols are global in php. so even nested function will be available from anywhere.

Comment: @zerkms: Are you saying that if I have another static method like `parent`, the `child` function will be accessible from it? I doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @zerkms: you forgot to add "in php" - nested functions are VERY BAD in php, just because php sucks so badly.

Comment: @Emanuil: well, just try then! ;-)

Comment: @stereofrog: i don't want to holywar here. we are talking in the context of the question (php-related one). point.

Comment: @zerkms: you should have said that before SCREAMING at him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lambda functions from PHP 5.3 and on:

```
public static function parent($param) {
  $child = function($param) {
    print($param);
  }

  $child($param);
}
```

If you need to do it with earlier versions of PHP try [create_function](https://www.php.net/create_function).

Comment: +1 Starting with PHP 5.3, he can even use [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) so he doesn't need to explicitly pass `$param`. That comes pretty close to what he's looking for I think

Answer (score 1):

I think that the global you call in `child()` does not refer to that scope. Try running it with really global variable.

Comment: The global in child() does not belong to the scope of the parent() function but to the real global scope.

Comment: I was thinking exactly this way - if he declares variable in parent function and then is trying to access it throught global in child - there is no chance.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this there would be to create an anonymous function inside your parent function, and then use the ''use'' keyword.

```
public static function parent($params) {
  function() use ($params) {
    print($params);
  }
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php